# How to bundle external tool dependencies with a python program?

Tags: conda

I have developed a python script which uses 3 different already developed tools (say tool#1, tool#2 and tool#3) internally. All these 3 tools need to be separately installed before I can run my python script.

I want to develop a method using which I can bundle all the 3 dependencies(tools) along with my python script and ship that in a single executable; such that whenever I want somebody else to use my script, he/she can install "that" executable and use my script without worrying about setting up conda environments.

Right now, I have created a conda environment inside which I have installed all the 3 tools which is the quickest way in my knowledge to get my script running.

## Export the environment in a YAML file

`conda env export > environment.yml`

## Install the exported dependencies using this YAML file

`conda env create -f environment.yml`

Therefore, I am looking for a way/method/tool for bundling all the dependencies with python script. I tried googling this however could not find anything.

Can someone point me the right direction? I just need pointers to tutorials or videos which can help me build such an executable.

If you need any further clarifications, please let me know.

Comment: Technically I think this is off-topic, but I'd like know the answer to this too. I think you will need to describe the dependencies, because there could be issues about ownership.

Comment: The problem with defining dependencies is that the script works for a pipeline solving a bioinformatics related problem which is not familiar to everyone.

Comment: Well I'm a bioinformatician and am not alone

Comment: @MichaelG. that's great to learn. I should have looked at your profile. Since you are also interested in the solution for this problem, how do you think we can improve on building this question(adding extra details) apart from letting others know about the dependencies.

Comment: I would point to packages such as ete3, which is part of the etetoolkit channel, that have a large number of dependencies such as PAML, clustalo, and PhyML and ask how did they have manage to achieve this list of dependencies for download within their channel.